# How to find all substrings that start and end with 1?

Tags: c++, algorithm

You are given a string of 0’s and 1’s you have to find all substrings in the string which starts and end with a 1.

For example, given 0010110010, output should be the six strings:

```
101
1011
1011001
11
11001
1001
```

Obviously there is an `O(N^2)` solution, but I'm looking for a solution with complexity on the order of `O(N)`. Is it possible?

Comment: Or you could just count the number of 1's and compute the number of possible (start-index, end-index) pairs in the usual way.

Comment: Are you looking for unique substrings? Otherwise the problem is pretty trivial: you would need to count the number of 1s. Let say that number is `n`. Now, in how many ways can you pick a start and end?

Comment: Just compute `nCr` where `n` is the number of `1s` and `r=2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously there is an `O(N^2)` solution, but I'm looking for a solution with complexity on the order of `O(N)`. Is it possible?

Let `k` be the number of `1`s in our input string. Then there are `O(k^2)` such substrings. Enumerating them must take at least `O(k^2)` time. If `k ~ N`, then enumerating them must take `O(N^2)` time.

The only way to get an `O(N)` solution is if we add the requirement that `k` is `o(sqrt(N))`. There cannot be an `O(N)` solution in the general case with no restriction on `k`.

An actual `O(k^2)` solution is straightforward:

```
std::string input = ...;

std::vector<size_t> ones;
ones.reserve(input.size());

// O(N) find the 1s
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < input.size(); ++idx) {
    if (input[idx] == '1') {
        ones.push_back(idx);
    }
}

// O(k^2) walk the indices
for (size_t i = 0; i < ones.size(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = i+1; j < ones.size(); ++j) {
        std::cout << input.substr(i, j - i + 1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Update** We have to account for the *lengths* of the substrings as well as the *number* of them. The total length of all the strings is `O(k * N)`, which is strictly greater than the previously claimed bound of `O(k^2)`. Thus, the `o(sqrt(N))` bound on `k` is insufficient - we actually need `k` to be `O(1)` in order to yield an `O(N)` solution.

Comment: + for the complexity discution.

Comment: Your solution is `O(N * k^2)`; you should also take the length of the substrings into account.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele The total length of all the substrings is only `O(N * k)`, so each one would be `O(N / k)` - which gets us to `O(Nk)`, not `O(N*k^2)`.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Still it's a good point, `O(Nk)` is strictly greater than `O(k^2)` and makes the restrictions for making an `O(N)` solution even more onerous... updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the same in `O(n)` with the following steps :

  1. Count the number of 1's.
  2. Let # of 1's be
  `x`
  , we return
  `x(x-1)/2`
  .

This quite trivially counts the number of possible pairs of 1's. 
The code itself is probably worth trying yourself!

***EDIT:***

If you want to return the substrings themselves, you must restrict the number of 1's in your substring in order to get some sort of `O(N)` solution *(or really `O(x)` where `x` is your # of 1's)* , as enumerating them in itself cannot be reduced in a general case from `O(N^2)` time complexity.

Comment: The OP has changed the requirements of the question.  Your answer really doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the number of substrings, and not the substrings themselves, you could probably pull it off by counting the number of pairs after doing an initial O(n) sum of the number of 1's you encounter

Comment: I need the substrings themselves

Comment: Then please state that in the question.  As of when everyone was answering this question you stated you needed the number of substrings, not the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `N` is supposed to be the number of `1`s in your string (or at least proportional to it, which is reasonable assuming a constant probability of `1` for each character):

If you need the substrings themselves, there's going to be `N(N-1)/2`, which is quadratic, so it's completely impossible to be less complex than quadratic.

Comment: The number of substrings is `O(k^2)` when there are `k` 1s in the string. This is not the same as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I kind of disagree with you, here; I think for OP `N` is the number of ones in the string; I agree that introducing `x` for `N` is totally confusing, though. Adding my definition, fixing naming.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class DistictSubstrings {

public static void main(String args[]) {
// a hash set

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter The string");
String s = in.nextLine();
int L = s.length();
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
// add elements to the hash set
for (int i = 0; i < L; ++i) {


  for (int j = 0; j < L-i ; ++j) {
    if(s.charAt(j)=='1'&&s.charAt(j+i)=='1')
    {
    hs.add(s.substring(j, j+i + 1));
    }

 }
}
Iterator it=hs.iterator();
    System.out.println("the string starts and endswith 1");
    System.out.println(hs.size());
while(it.hasNext())
{
System.out.println(it.next()+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="1001010001";
for(int i=0;i<=s.length()-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<=s.length()-1;j++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(j)=='1' && s.charAt(i)=='1' && i<j)
        {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i,j+1));
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually seems to be the `O(N^2)` solution. Ahmed specifically asked if there is a better performing (`O(N)`) solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following python code will help you to find all substrings that starts and ends with 1.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep 26 14:25:14 2017

@author: Veeramani Natarajan
"""
# Python Implementation to find all substrings that start and end with 1

# Function to calculate the count of sub-strings 
def calcCount(mystring):
    cnt=-1
    index=0    
    while(index<len(mystring)):
        if(mystring[index]=='1'):
            cnt += 1
        index += 1
    return cnt


mystring="0010110010";
index=0;
overall_cnt=0

while(index<len(mystring)):
    if(mystring[index]=='1'):
        partcount=calcCount(mystring[index:len(mystring)])
        overall_cnt=overall_cnt+partcount
#        print("index is",index)
#        print("passed string",mystring[index:len(mystring)])
#        print("Count",partcount,"overall",overall_cnt)
    index=index+1
# print the overall sub strings count
print (overall_cnt)
```

***Note:
Though this is not O(N) solution,  i believe it will help someone to understand the python implementation of the above problem statement.***

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution is definitely possible using DP.
We take an array of pairs where the first element in each pair denotes the number of substrings upto that index and the second element denotes the number of substrings starting with 1 **up to but not including that index**. (So, if the char at that index is 1, the second element won't count the substring [1, 1])
We simply iterate through the array and build the solution incrementally as we do in DP and after the end of the loop, we have the final value in the pair's first element in the last index of our array. Here's the code:

```
int getoneonestrings(const string &str)
{
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    vector< pair<int, int> > dp(n, make_pair(0, 0));
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '0')
        {
            dp[i].first = dp[i - 1].first;
        }
        else
        {
            dp[i].first = dp[i - 1].first + dp[i - 1].second +
                (str[i - 1] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
        }
        dp[i].second = dp[i - 1].second + (str[i - 1] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return dp[n - 1].first;
}
```